# Ruby on Rails Pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I'm having trouble getting a set of data to paginate in ruby. I already have one example (newsfeed of posts by users you are 'following')

_feed_item.html.erb

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
<%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
<span class="user">
<%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
</span>
<span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>  
<span class="timestamp">
Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
</span>
# not part of the code - just a placeholder for a like button I'm writing
<span class="likebtn-wrapper" data-lang="en"></span>
##########################
<% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
<%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
title: feed_item.content %>
<% end %>
</li>
```

_feed.html.erb

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
<ol class="microposts">
<%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
</ol>
<%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% else %>
```

home.html.erb (to render the newsfeed)

```
<%= render 'shared/feed' %>
```

Because the default Home only renders posts by users who you are following - I created a "Global" post index that simply lists all posts saved to the database.

global.html.erb

```
Global Feed |  
<%= User.count %> Total Users |
<%= Micropost.count %> Total Posts<br />
<% Micropost.all.each do |micropost| %>
Global Post Number: <%= micropost.id %> <br />
<%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %> <br />
<%= micropost.content %><br />
<span class="timestamp">
Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
</span>
<% end %>
```

I tried using the same sort of technique used in for the newsfeed but it doesn't work. How would I go about paginating the results similar to the users newsfeed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use

```
<% Micropost.all.each do |micropost| %>
```

in your global.html.erb file.

Instead use `<%= render @feeds %>` in this file. Which will process every feed using _feed.html.erb

In your microposts_controller.rb you should have sth like:

```
  def index
    @feeds = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: <%= render @feeds %> produces an error

C:/Sites/NFE/app/views/static_pages/global.html.erb:28: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

The _feed.html only grabs posts from users you are following. The global page needs to display all posts even if you aren't following that person.